# Stack is one kind of queue

Tags: data-structures

I have recently been doing an assignment where one of the problem is

"Prove that, stack is one kind of queue".

I have already searched in forums and popular search engines about this topic. However, I was unable to find any related information.
Is it really true that stack is one kind of queue? If so, how?

Comment: A stack can be considered as as 'Last-In, First-Out' queue. However, the prompt to 'prove' something suggests that a stack and a queue are rigorously defined. Is that the case?

Comment: No, it isn't actually required to rigorously define the statement. Any kind of explanation that shows stack can be considered as queue is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stack can be implemented by wrapping a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) in the following way. When pushing an element to the stack, it gets a priority defined as the number of elements already in the priority queue, which ensures that it has the highest priority; for popping an element, take the one with the highest priority. In total, this means that a stack can be seen as a special case of a priority queue.

Answer (score 1):

**Stacks**

A stack is a container of objects that are inserted and removed according to the last-in first-out (LIFO) principle. In the pushdown stacks only two operations are allowed: `push` the item into the stack, and `pop` the item out of the stack. A stack is a limited access data structure - elements can be added and removed from the stack only at the top. push adds an item to the top of the stack, pop removes the item from the top. A helpful analogy is to think of a stack of books; you can remove only the top book, also you can add a new book on the top.

**Queues**

A queue is a container of objects (a linear collection) that are inserted and removed according to the first-in first-out (FIFO) principle. An excellent example of a queue is a line of students in the food court of the UC. New additions to a line made to the back of the queue, while removal (or serving) happens in the front. In the queue only two operations are allowed `enqueue` and `dequeue`. Enqueue means to insert an item into the back of the queue, dequeue means removing the front item.

**Now to your point** : 
Generally you can not delete or insert the data (node) in between. This characteristic is applicable in both the data structure. So in my opinion this could be one of the reason.